# Find text inside javascript tag using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to find a text change regularly inside javascript tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
flashplayer: "player.swf",
file:"filename",
provider: "rtmp",
streamer:"rtmp://192.168.1.1/file?wmsAuthSign=RANDOM-114-Character==",
height:500,
width:500,
});
</script>
```

How to get RANDOM-114-Character (or full value of 'streamer' flashvars) using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I just have no idea to do this.

Comment: You can get the content of the script using `simple html dom` then, as Yurii suggested, parse it with regex to get the string you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regular expression:

> preg_match ($pattern, $java_script, $matches);

Pattern depends, if the variable 'wmsAuthSign' is unique. For example:

> $pattern = '/wmsAuthSign=(.*?)==/';
>
> preg_match ($pattern, $java_script, $matches);
>
> echo $matches[1];

But you can always start your pattern from 'streamer' for example if 'wmsAuthSign' is not unique.